# How to return redirect response from aiohttp.web server

Tags: python, aiohttp

How do I return a response with HTTP redirect in an [aiohttp](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io) server handler?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Documentation: http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web_quickstart.html#redirects

```
async def handler(request):
    raise web.HTTPFound('/redirect')
```

The exception classes and their corresponding HTTP status codes: http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web_quickstart.html#exceptions

```
  * 300 - HTTPMultipleChoices
  * 301 - HTTPMovedPermanently
  * 302 - HTTPFound
  * 303 - HTTPSeeOther
  * 304 - HTTPNotModified
  * 305 - HTTPUseProxy
  * 307 - HTTPTemporaryRedirect
  * 308 - HTTPPermanentRedirect
```